# PRI vs PRIMARY get primary field of table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I was researching on how to get the primary key of a table in mysql and found the following solution which returns no rows (fails):

```
show columns from `projects` where `Key` = "PRIMARY"
```

Yet this works just fine and returns the primary key:

```
show columns from `projects` where `Key` = "PRI"
```

What is the difference between PRI and PRIMARY? Do different phpmyadmins have different notations for primary fields?

Answer (score 1):

The `key` attribute in the metadata is three characters.

I think that `'Primary'` is truncated for the comparison.